# Absolute positioning messed up in Safari

Tags: css, safari

I tried to do a mouseover fade effect with jQuery. The idea is to have two images positioned on top of each other in this way.

```
<img class="img-circle webdesign " src="assets/img/webdesign_.png" style="position: absolute;" >
<img class="img-circle" src="assets/img/webdesign_hover.png">
```

It works well with Chrome. Screenshot ( http://cl.ly/image/0f3M0f2q1t2S )

However, i am having this issue with Safari ( http://cl.ly/image/44290O3n1X0b )

You can see both images when the page loads even though, the grayscale one should appear on top of the coloured one and hides the latter.

Suggestions?

Comment: Make both `position:absolute`, set the `top` and `left` properties of both to be the same, set the `z-index` of the top one to be greater. Or, even better, keep the bottom one completely hidden with `display:none`, and toggle their visibilities together with jQuery.

Comment: Setting explicit `top` and `left` should do. `z-index` won't help unless you need the former on top of the latter.

Comment: @Jan Yes, but since he intends to switch the ordering with effects that was intended to provide the mechanism for that. I prefer the other method anyway though...

Comment: image links are broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<img class="img-circle webdesign " src="assets/img/webdesign_.png">
<img class="img-circle" src="assets/img/webdesign_hover.png" style='display:none;'>
```

JS

```
$('.img-circle').mouseenter(function() {
    $('.img-circle').toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.img-circle {
    position: absolute;
    top: ???;
    left: ???;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I also had some problems (only with Safari) with an element that had absolute positioning. 
I fixed the issue by specifying the left and right properties:

```css
.element{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was a little different, but the solution was to add `position: relative;` to the parent element (and in my case, `height: 100%`) and this made Chrome and Safari behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me in a similar challenge:

```
position: absolute;
top: 8px;
margin-left: 14px;
```